# How can I dynamically update all rows with dynamic data each row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I have about 300 rows. What I want to do is update all the table with MySQL.

What I want to achieve:

I have a table with set of rows like

```
+----------------------------------+
| name              | code         |
+----------------------------------+
| test              | (null)       |
| test              | (null)       |
+----------------------------------+
```

Now I want to update all the rows in this table. What I want to update them to is
the code should start from `A` then `B` then `c` and so on and after it reaches `z` it should again start from `AA`. So I need a var which sets value for itself.

Expected final result:

```
+----------------------------------+
| name              | code         |
+----------------------------------+
| test              | A            |
| test              | B            |
.
.
| test              | z            |
| test              | AA           |
| test              | AB           |
+----------------------------------+
```

and so on.

Comment: What is the version of your mysql?

Comment: `MYSQL 8` @Shawn.X

Comment: you need to write cursor to do this

Comment: how can I write that ... can you help?

Comment: See [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html)

Comment: Personally, I would use PHP to write the MySQL. It would be easier. This is not the duplicate shown, either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this SQL as below:

```
select
    name,
    char(row_number() over(order by name) - ceil(row_number() over(order by name)/27.0 - 1)*27+64) as abc_group_num
from
    my_table
```